# Passing Class Memeber function to different class

Tags: c++, class

I'm sure this can be done, but it seems really complex so i will do my best to explain.

I have a basic class

```
class TestClass {
public:

    void Test1(int a) { cout << "You chose option 1. The answer is " << a << "\n"; }
    void Test2(int b) { cout << "You chose option 2. The answer is " << b << "\n"; }
    void Run(int i) {
        if (i == 0) {
            Test1(2);
        }
        else {
            Test1(5);
        }
    }
};
```

And also a secondary class

```
class ExecuteFunctions {
public:
    template<class _Fn, class... _Args>
    void CPU(_Fn&& _Fx, _Args&&... _Ax);
};

template<class _Fn, class... _Args>
void ExecuteFunctions::CPU(_Fn&& _Fx, _Args&&... _Ax)
{
    _Fx(forward<_Args>(_Ax)...);
}
```

But when i try and call TestClass::Run using the execute class from main it wont compile saying it doesnt match the argument list.

```
Execute.CPU(TestClass::Run,Option);
```

I can call the function without the ExecuteClass and can also call it in a new thread

```
int Option = 1;
TestClass T;
thread TestThread(&TestClass::Run, &T, Option);
```

Is what i'm trying to do actually possible?

Comment: Think about what is different between the calls.

Comment: `Execute.CPU(TestClass::Run,Option);` <-- for this to work, you need an instance of `TestClass`, and you need to invoke the function using indirect-member-invocation syntax. Consider using [`std::bind()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind) instead: `Execute.CPU(std::bind(&TestClass::Run, someTestClassObject), Option);`

Comment: The C++ standard does not allow you to write anything with a name starting with an underscore followed by a capital letter ([cppreference link](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/identifiers#In_declarations)). You should probably remove the leading underscore from your template parameter names.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to have an instance of object to call your run method on, simply `_Fx(forward<_Args>(_Ax)...);` is not enough. The fix is as follows:

```
ExecuteFunctions Execute;
int Option = 1;
TestClass T;
Execute.CPU(std::bind(&TestClass::Run, &T, std::placeholders::_1),Option);
```

Comment: Note that if, in the more complete example, the function `_Fn` might last longer than whatever method calls `ExecuteFunction::CPU`, you’ll need to make a `TestClass` instance which also lasts longer.

Comment: Thanks, works, hadn't used bind before and didn't know about the placeholder parameters